# Issues with height/width properties after uninstalling CalendarKit

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, calendarkit

I recently removed the line

`pod 'CalendarKit', '~>0.5.0'` from my podfile in an ios project.

I then ran `pod deintegrate` and then reinstalled all the pods. However, Now, I'm getting a bunch of build errors of the form:

`Value of type 'UILabel' has no member 'height'; did you mean 'fs_height'?`

`Value of type 'UIView?' has no member 'width'`

`Value of type 'UIView?' has no member 'x'`

Why would removing a line from my podfile cause these changes? Is there something here I'm missing (like would it change the swift version or somthing?)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was because the `CalendarKit` pod also uninstalled `Neon`, which defined many of these properties. Problem solved!